# mrt:peity how data binded

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper, atmosphere.js

I installed mrt:peity from atmospherejs. i am not sure how data is binded. from package file it seems expecting data/chart in helper. however I noticed when i do

```
Template.todolist.helpers({
    todoitems: function(){
       return Todolist.find({"status":{"$ne":"validated"}}, {data:1, chart:1})
    }
});
```

it works fine. but when i do

```
Template.todoitem.helpers({
data:function(){
    return [moment().diff(this.ts,"days"),this.eta]
},
chart:function(){
    return "pie"
}
})
```

it no longer works. can anyone helps on this?

---

Edit:
I don't need wrap todoitem template around {{peity}} (peity package). i think it breaks this hierarchy. it works if i do this

```
Template.todolist.helpers({
  todoitems: function(){
    return _.map(Todolist.find({}).fetch(), function(v, k){
  return {chart:"pie", data:[moment().diff(v["ts"],"days"),v["eta"]], taskname:v["taskname"]}
})
```

Comment: it turns out I mess the template hierarchy see Edit

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check before you can look at getting it to work:

The first is the projections need to be placed in `fields`. (This is if you need this. If you use it the other fields wont work (`ts` and `eta` will be hidden if you use a projection)

```
return Todolist.find({"status":{"$ne":"validated"}}, {fields:{data:1, chart:1}})
```

The second is `data` is a reserved keyword. You need to use something else. You can't use a helper with the name `data` since it would conflict with the internal data context variable used by Blaze.

Looking at your code its hard to tell what you're trying to do. I'm assuming if you need to use `[moment().diff(this.ts,"days"),this.eta]` you don't need the projection given by `fields`:

```
some_other_word:function(){
    return [moment().diff(this.ts,"days"),this.eta]
},
```

Then use `{{some_other_word}}` instead of `{{data}}`